# Force QLPreviewController into Edit mode on iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, quicklook, pencilkit

Just presenting a QLPreviewController to view an image (on iOS13.) Ideally I'd like it to switch into edit mode automatically (and so present the PencilKit stuff.)

Anyone know how to do this? The setEditing: approach (used on UITableViewControllers) doesn't seem to work in this instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`setEditing` is documented in `UIViewController` and says that `subclasses` must implement it to react to the editing.

I've tried setting it in both instance creation and `completion` handler of `presentViewController` and it's not working, meaning that `QLPreviewController` doesn't implement it.

tl;dr: There is no standard way to enable editing unless you hack into navigationBar items and try to 'press' the edit icon.

Comment: Is there anyway to hack into the navigation bar? I tried and it comes back as nil.